# How can I use edgesIgnoringSafeArea in SwiftUI, but make a child view respect the safe area?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm building a UI is SwiftUI with a list view, and I want to put a panel over part of the list view with a button on it.

On devices with a safe area at the bottom (that don't have a physical home button) I want the panel to go to the bottom of the screen. But I want to make sure that the button on the panel doesn't extend into the safe area.

In my example code, the `HStack` is the panel that contains the button. I tried adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` to it, but that doesn't allow it to extend to the bottom. This is kind of confusing to me, because the List that's in the same `ZStack` extends into the bottom safe area.

When I add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` to the `ZStack`, the `HStack` (blue panel) is allowed to extend into the safe area at the bottom of the screen. This is what I want, but then once I do that, how can I tell the `Button` that's a child of the `HStack` to *not* ignore the safe area?

I know how I would do this in UIKit, but I'm really hoping to be able to build this UI in SwiftUI. I could manually add some padding or Spacers to add extra padding under the `Button` to account for the safe area, but then there would be extra spacing on devices with a home button that don't have a bottom safe area. I'd like to figure out an elegant solution where I can rely on the system to define its safe areas instead of manually defining any spacing numerically or creating conditional situations for different devices.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {

                    List {
                        Text("Item 1")
                        Text("Item 2")
                        Text("Item 3")
                    }

                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // do something
                        }){
                            Text("Button")
                                .font(.title)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.green)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                        }.padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }.background(Color.blue).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of a failed attempt at what I want]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can access the height of the safe area using a GeometryReader. Then you could use the height of the safe area as bottom padding or offset on your button.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {

                List {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        // do something
                    }){
                        Text("Button")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    Spacer()
                }.background(Color.blue)
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside a NavigationView, also a bad answer (see @Joe Susnick's answer).

Comment: Unfortunately using GeometryReader can create all sorts of spacing problems... it expands to take up all available space.

Answer (score 134):

Whatever view you draw in the background modifier will use the frame of the view it's modifying. So you need to tell THAT view to ignore the safe area.

```
.background(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom))
```

Comment: using `.vertical` instead of `.bottom` you can extend the background at the top too

Comment: How would you do this if the background is an Image, because in that case it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, this must be the best answer. It seems weird at first, but we have to keep this pattern while we using SwiftUI!

Answer (score 9):

`edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/edgesignoringsafearea(_:)).

Use the following:

```
.background(Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @Joe Susnick's answer, the full code is:

```swift
VStack {

}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color(red: 0.357, green: 0.784, blue: 0.016, opacity: 0.5).ignoresSafeArea()
)
```

Anything inside of VStack respects the safe area whereas the background fills the whole screen.

Answer (score -1):

in case it helps, for me the solution was to set a padding based on the current keyboard height which I am getting from this class

```swift
@Observable
class KeyboardObserver {
    private var keyboardHeightPublisher: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge(
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .map { notification in
                    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
                        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
                        return keyboardRectangle.height
                    }
                    return .zero
                },

            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
                .map { _ in CGFloat.zero }
        )
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    init() {
        keyboardHeightPublisher.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] height in
            withAnimation {
                self?.keyboardHeight = height
            }
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```