# Is there a edgesIgnoringSafeArea none value?

Tags: swiftui

With the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` you can ignore all safe area, but is there also something like .none so you can switch between the two via something like `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(isFullscreen ? .all : .none)`? Or how would you achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be easily done. Here is some example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var isFullscreen = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            self.isFullscreen.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Fullscreen")
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(isFullscreen ? .all : .init()) // This is what you need.       
} }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as a "real" `.none` since it doesn't reverse `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(:)` from superviews ... In this example it probably just says "ignore nothing" but not explicitly "ignore none and undo previeous ignores", which is what I am trying to achieve. Any Ideas? :)

Comment: This was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432382/3078330